# ¿como funciona el Error.captureStackTrace( ) con los siguientes parametros, this, this.constructor?'

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy manejando errores, pero tengo este pequeño problema, vi este ejemplo, se que la funcion captureStackTrace() me permite capturar en un pila los errores, pero los parametros que tiene no entiendo su funcionalidad, no se para donde apunta el this ni el this.constructor